# Incorrect transform position in Chrome when using percent

Tags: css, google-chrome, webkit, css-transforms

When using transform with percent value on container that has float width (for ex. 800.63px) Chrome always rounds position in pixels incorrectly. 
This typically happens with em/rem width in combination with percent (see example below):

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="wrap">
    <div class="slider">
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**SCSS:**

```
.container {
  width: 38rem;
}

.wrap {
  width: 33%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.slider {
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-size: 0;
  transform: translate3d(-1000%,0,0);
}

.item {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 8rem;
  width: 100%;
  background: limegreen;

  &:nth-child(even) {
    background: orangered;
  }
}
```

The result is some part of next slide is always visible. Looks like Chrome first rounds the item width and then multiplies it by percent value.

Is there any known workaround for this? If I do the math in JS and use px values in transform then everything is (almost) perfect, but shouldn't it "just work" with percents too?

Please, see fiddle for working example: https://jsfiddle.net/Lumh07te/37/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the way you set your sizes.

Instead of the slider having width 100%, and needing a maximum transform of 1000%, set it to a width of 1000%, and a needed maximum transform of 100%.

And the items width is now 10% instead of 100%

in your original code, wrap has a width that is not integer, but than in the layout is forced to render as an integer value in pixels. Then , translating a 1000% of this value multiplies the rounding errors by 10.  If you instead set the width to 1000%, the rounding to pixels is done on this size, and then it is mutiplyed by values less than 1 (0.5, 0.6, 0.7.. ) or 1 at a maximum

```css
.container {
  width: 38rem;
}

.wrap {
  width: 33%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.slider {
  width: 1300%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-size: 0;
  transform: translateX(calc(-500%  / 13));
  transition: transform 0.4s;
}

.test {
    height: 50px;
}
.test:hover ~ .wrap .slider {
  transform: translateX(calc(-800%  / 13));
}

.item {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 8rem;
  width: calc(100% / 13);
  background: limegreen;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.item:nth-child(even) {
  background: orangered;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="test">test</div>
  <div class="wrap">
    <div class="slider">
      <div class="item">1</div>
      <div class="item">2</div>
      <div class="item">3</div>
      <div class="item">4</div>
      <div class="item">5</div>
      <div class="item">6</div>
      <div class="item">7</div>
      <div class="item">8</div>
      <div class="item">9</div>
      <div class="item">10</div>
      <div class="item">11</div>
      <div class="item">12</div>
      <div class="item">13</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea! It is interesting that the other way around works better. There are some problems, though. I can't really use animations in this case, because this whole transformation must be controlled via JavaScript. And if I do the same thing with transforms I need to do the math in JS anyway, please see the updated example: https://jsfiddle.net/oq0aLtp1/3/ As you can see, I have to set the width for items for each slider length (one for 7 items and other for 13) and I have to use translate values like -84.59% for each step, which also may results in rounding errors adding up.

Comment: Also, maybe you have an idea why the original example does not work in Chrome? The specific solution is welcome, but for me it's much more important to understand what's wrong with the original example. Thanks again!

Comment: The use of an animation was only to show that the display is ok at any point in the slider. I have the code to be more similar to your request. Hover on test to make the slider change

Comment: Indeed, it looks much more elegant this way. Thanks for your efforts!